# creating new instances in node.js; require-uncached thread safety

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns, thread-safety

I have a system that will be serving a high throughput of HTTP requests, and I am trying to load a custom module with a new instance for each request. The reason I want to create a new instance is because within the module is an object that is shared across promises in multiple promise chains. I would like the object to be isolated for each instance of this module. I realize this may be considered an anti-pattern in some shops, but I like having a single dynamic object that can be used across many complex promise chains, as it allows my promises to be reusable in many different ways. I like how the promise chains organize my code, and the pattern itself fits my needs well, but would like to hear about alternatives if any. Here is an example:

```
var reusableObject;

module.exports = function() {
    return {
        myFunction: function() {
            return somePromise()
            .then(anotherPromise)
            .then(yetAnotherPromise)
            .then(function() { return reusableObject; })
        }
}
```

The second part of my question is in regards to instantiating new modules with node's native module loader, require. I tried, unsuccessfully, to create new instances of my module with the `new` operator using `var service = new (require('myModule'))()`. My best guess is that underneath, node's require is fetching the module from cache.

I came across a module called [require-uncached](https://github.com/sindresorhus/require-uncached), and voila, I was successfully able to create new instances of my module. However, when glancing at the [code](https://github.com/sindresorhus/require-uncached/blob/master/index.js), I am concerned that the require-uncached module loader is not thread-safe. I realized it's time to get some expert analysis. Any help is appreicated. tia

Comment: Did you actually install, load and configure RequireJS?? If not, you're not using RequireJS. (It is a [specific product](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html). Usually used in clients, not server-side. It is possible to use it in Node.js but it is not present by default.)

Comment: My mistake, I meant node's native module loader, the require() function. I've edited the post to correct that.